# rewrite url's but for a different domain

Tags: url, url-rewriting

We're in a need to rewrite some url's in our site (we use NGINX) so they will appear as a different domain.

For example we want www.mydomain.com/category to become www.newdomain.com

Also any related Url, should follow the same path

For example,

www.mydomain.com/category/news to become www.newdomain.com/news

Is this possible from server side and if yes, how can we do it ?

Important Notice: The mydomain.com/category is a "virtual" folder, I mean that there is no directory in the server with files but it's being created automatically from the script.

Best Regards